# Pass ID attribute of hyperlink to form when submitting form via clicking link

Tags: javascript, html

Taking the following examples:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="go.php?u=word.other" id="word.other">word other</a></li>
    <li><a href="go.php?u=cat.dog" id="cat.dog">cat dog</a></li>
    <li><a href="go.php?u=tree.leaf" id="tree.leaf">tree leaf</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to work out how to change the hyperlinks so that instead of straight links to `go.php`, clicking the link submits a form.

I tried this, but it's pretty clunky as it hard-codes a form next in each list-item:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="go.php?u=gnaw.bouncy"d>gnawbouncy</a> <form action="go.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="u" value="gnaw.bouncy"><input type="submit"></form></li>
    <li><a href="go.php?u=sledder.slothful">sledderslothful</a> <form action="go.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="u" value="sledder.slothful"><input type="submit"></form></li>
    <li><a href="go.php?u=intrepid.shade">intrepidshade</a> <form action="go.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="u" value="intrepid.shade"><input type="submit"></form></li>
</ul>
```

My next thought was to use javascript to submit a form using a hyperlink instead.

However - while I have seen routes to submit a forum using a link - e.g. using jQuery:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-submit-a-form-using-jQuery-click-event

That only works when one link is used to submit the form.

I then tried this:

```js
var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
if (lists.length) {
    lists.forEach(list => {
        list.addEventListener('click', e => {
            if (!e.target.id) return;
            var id = e.target.id; // this is the id from the link
            console.log(id);
            e.preventDefault();
            // $("#testing").submit();
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
            
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="word.other">word.other</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="cat.dog">cat.dog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tree.leaf">tree.leaf</a></li>           
    </ul>

</div>          

<form action="go.php" method="post" name="testing" id="testing"><input type="hidden" name="u"></form>
```

I can see that clicking one of the list-item links is picked up by the JS as the console.log fires and displays the ID of the link.

However - how can I achieve the result that clicking on the link submits the form and passes the ID attribute of the clicked link to the `go.php` page via the `un` hidden form attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some Javascript to get the Form, then set the `.value` of the only child to `e.target.id` and then call `submit()` on the form to run it.

```js
var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
if (lists.length) {
    lists.forEach(list => {
        list.addEventListener('click', e => {
            if (!e.target.id) return;
            var id = e.target.id; // this is the id from the link
            console.log(id);
            e.preventDefault();
            
            const f = document.querySelector('form');
            f.children[0].value = e.target.id;
            f.submit();
            
            // Or a saver way if there are more elements in the Form
            // f.querySelector('input[name="u"]').value = e.target.id;
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
            
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="word.other">word.other</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="cat.dog">cat.dog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tree.leaf">tree.leaf</a></li>           
    </ul>

</div>          

<form action="go.php" method="post" name="testing" id="testing"><input type="hidden" name="u"></form>
```

Comment: Glad it worked! One more note btw: [You might not need Jquery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)! The `submit` on a form is just native JS ;)